# Where is autonormalize in 2.8?

Tags: weight-painting

I saw a tutorial on YouTube, he used Auto normalized which used to be under brush. In the today version of 2.8 isn't there anymore.
Where can I find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest Blender and press <kbd>N</kbd> on your keyboard >> Tools >> Options >> Auto Normalize

[image]
Good Luck

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit old but it was the only post on google who show this question. I found a solution for that. Instead of accessing the brush option through the toolbar, select "context" in the sidebar. There are also the brush options. Hope i could help anyone :)

[image]